# How to get a String value from the UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, string, uidatepicker

I'm trying to allow the user to select a time with a `UIDatePicker` and when that time comes that matches the timepicker, a code will be implemented. I'm trying to find out how to get a `UIDatePicker`'s selected time to be a string so I can use it in a separate part of my app. I found a few questions on StackOverFlow in Objective-C on how to convert the `UIDatePicker`'s  input into a string, but I have not found anything in Swift. Please help.

```
func setDateAndTime() {
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateTimeDisplay.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date) + " " + dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    datePicker.textInputMode = "\(dtpk.date)"
    datePicker.textInputContextIdentifier = "\(dtpk.date)"
}
```

I didn't get any errors on this code, but my app always crashed when `setDateAndTime()` was executed

Comment: This question is too broad. Stack Overflow is not a place where people will write code for you, it's a place to ask specific questions to receive help and guidance. Start by posting the code you've tried, specifics on what you're looking to achieve, what didn't work, etc. The more specific you are, the better.

Comment: I added in the code that I tried. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Why do you attempt to concatenate two calls to the date formatter? You don't need two calls. One call will have both the date and time.

Comment: [Edit] your question with details about the crash. Which line crashes? What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

add Target for Datepicker

```
func dateChanged(sender : UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatr = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatr.dateFormat = "dd MMMM, h:mm a"
        let strDate = dateFormatr.string(from: (datePicker?.date)!)
        print(strDate)
    }
```

Comment: Do not use this code as-is. It will crash if `datePicker` is `nil`.

Comment: And why hardcode a specific date format when the OP shows they want to use short style date and time?

Comment: I used this code.... it does not crash. But instead when i change the date i have a UILabel that is supposed to show it. The UILable is equal to strDate but the date doesnt show up. How would i have the date show up on a UILabel?

Comment: 'dateTimeDisplay.text = strDate' the "dateTimeDsiplay" is the UILabel. When this code is read the placeholder text is removed but it stays blank.

Comment: I thing you need change textcolor may be its same as background color

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add a Action method on  UIDatePicker like this:
yourDatePickerView1.addTarget(self, action: Selector("pickerAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
And then do something like this in your handler:
func pickerAction(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    var strPickerDate = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    // do what you want to do with the string.
}
```